# Send String from server to client - save it as textfile

Tags: java, sockets, fileoutputstream, printwriter

I know how to send a file from a server to a client but how do I send a textstring to the client where the client save the string as a file? Should I use `PrintWriter` for this issue?

This is the code for sending a file from server to client:
[Sending files through sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099636/sending-files-through-sockets)

What I want to do is to (instead of sending a file), sending a `String` from the server and let the client receive it and save it as a file.

```
public class SocketFileExample {
    static void server() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3434);
        Socket socket = ss.accept();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("send.jpg");
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        copy(in, out);
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }

    static void client() throws IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 3434);
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("recv.jpg");
        copy(in, out);
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }

    static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    server();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();

        client();
    }
}
```

Comment: means you mean to say that, server will send a string and client will save that string in a file...???

Comment: @NiRRaNjANRauT - yes thats correct - (string holds UTF-8 characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in that case use `ObjectOutputStream` at server side to write String and use `ObjectInputStream` at client side to read String coming from server..

so your server() method will look like this..

```
static void server() throws IOException {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3434);
    Socket socket = ss.accept();
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
    oout.writeObject("your string here");
    oout.close();
}
```

and client() method will look like this..

```
static void client() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 3434);
    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
    ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(in);
    String stringFromServer = (String) oin.readObject();
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("received.txt");
    writer.write(stringFromServer);
    in.close();
    writer.close();
}
```

also throw `ClassNotFoundException` in main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {.......}
```

done...