# Server and Client sending file Java

Tags: java, file, bufferedinputstream, bufferedoutputstream

I am writing a program that has a client and server where the client will send a img file to the server.  The code below is for the server where it will get stuck on that while loop from `obIn.read` blocking on its last run, so it never is able to return -1 and break the loop.  It does break the loop for my Client.  So I tried to flush it after the loop on the Client but it doesn't seem to do any good. I don't want to close obOut because that will in return close the socket which I want to keep open. The server end is where it receives the bites from the obIn(inputstream that is an instance variable) and writes it to a file that I have created.

```
                  //server receives file
                    File file = new File("image/image.png");
                    BufferedOutputStream fileOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1000];
                    int c = 0;
                    while((c = obIn.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                        fileOut.write(bytes, 0, c);
                        fileOut.flush();
                        System.out.println(c);
                    }
                    System.out.println(c);
                    fileOut.close();
                    System.out.println("File Created");
```

---

```
                //Client
                String imgPath = in.nextLine();
                File file = new File(imgPath);

                BufferedInputStream fileIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1000];
                int c = 0;
                while((c = fileIn.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    obOut.write(bytes, 0, c);
                    obOut.flush();
                    System.out.println(c);
                }
                obOut.write(bytes, 0, 1000);
                obOut.flush();
                System.out.println(c);
                fileIn.close();
                System.out.println("File Sent");
```

This image is the output where the server is on top and the client is on bottom.  That is where I found that the Server is stuck blocking.

[image]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099636/sending-files-through-sockets) is where I found this method and tried making it work for my setup.  This is my first time working with streams.

Comment: To send `-1` you need to close() writer (here `obOut`). If you don't want to do that, lets say you want to send many files, then you need to create your own *protocol* (rules of speaking between client and server). Such protocol should state that first you are informing server about how many bytes it should expect (length of file), then instead of waiting for -1 you are simply counting how many bytes arrived and after all of them were received server can do other things, or wait for info about other task it should handle (like receiving another file).

Answer (score 0):

In your client class try replacing `write` and `flush` function out side of while loop with `obOut.close();`